# sudo does not allow me to run cp

Tags: linux, centos, sudo

Executing the following command on a CentOS 5 box:

```
$ sudo cp file1  file2
```

gives me the following error:

> Sorry user my_username is not allowed to execute '/bin/cp file1 file2' as root on site_name.com

How can root access not be enough?

Comment: Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: sudo is more than just "giving you root access". It has fine grained controls that let you restrict commands the user can run, as you've noticed here.

Comment: Sounds like limited sudo permissions in your `/etc/sudoers` file. If you don't control your sudo configuration you're not going to be able to do anything about this. `sudo` can be configured to allow only specific commands to be run with escalated privileges, which appears to be the case here... see `man sudoers` or google "sudo configuration" for more details.

Answer (score 10):

How is your sudoers file set up? This command doesn't say that root can't cp, but instead you aren't allowed to use cp AS root.

You should have: `my_username ALL=(ALL) ALL` in the sudoers file

Comment: Adding the line you've suggested to the sudoers file is overly lenient, and defeats one of the primary purposes of sudo: restricting which commands may be run with the privileges of another user. OP should read and understand `man sudoers`, and (assuming she/he has control over it) make adjustments wisely.

Comment: not only lenient, but dangerous, and very bad practice.  as Eli Heady states, the answer is "man sudoers"

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try running `sudo -l`, which will give you a listing of what permissions you have, according to the local `sudo` configuration. Eg: on my Macbook, I get:

```
: cez@rhk; sudo -l
Password:
Matching Defaults entries for cez on this host:
    env_reset, env_keep+=BLOCKSIZE, env_keep+="COLORFGBG COLORTERM", env_keep+=__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING,
    env_keep+="CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC
    LC_TIME", env_keep+="LINES COLUMNS", env_keep+=LSCOLORS, env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK, env_keep+=TZ,
    env_keep+="DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY", env_keep+="EDITOR VISUAL"

User cez may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) ALL
: cez@rhk;
```

The `(ALL) ALL` part means that my user can run any commands as any user (AFAICS).

Answer (score 1):

sudo does not implicitly give you root access.

I would take a look in /etc/sudoers